# Get eclipse syntax coloring for java in plugin for eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to create a plugin for eclipse that among other things needs to get the syntax coloring of a java file. Is there any way that this is possible? I've tried looking in the source code to see where eclipse calls a method to determine the style of a certain part of the source code, but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: The Eclipse editor uses information from the [Eclipse JDT Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html) to determine syntax coloring. You need to understand how Eclipse editors work to follow how this is done, it is not a simple process.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks a lot! With that little push in the right direction I managed create the syntax coloring myself.